# Indexed variables (symbolic arrays) with ModelingToolkit.jl

Tags: julia

I would like use ModelingToolkit.jl to solve large nonlinear systems of equations. Unfortunately, using symbolic arrays with NonlinearSystem gives a method error:

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching hasmetadata(::Vector{Num}, ::Type{Symbolics.VariableDefaultValue})
```

Is there a way of solving nonlinear equations with indexed variables with ModelingToolkit?

Code example:

```
using ModelingToolkit, NonlinearSolve
vars = @variables x
@named works = NonlinearSystem([], vars, [])

vars = @variables x[1:3]
@named fails = NonlinearSystem([], vars, [])

eqs = [x[j] ~ j for j ∈ 1:3]
@named also_fails = NonlinearSystem(eqs, vars, [])
```

Comment: That's a bug. Can you open an issue?

Comment: Sure, will do. Is it a bug in NonlinearSolve or ModelingToolkit?

Comment: It's a ModelingToolkit bug. It seems that system hasn't been made compatible with symbolic arrays.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris comments, it is a bug and now an open issue here:
https://github.com/SciML/ModelingToolkit.jl/issues/1406